# Update a section of a page after a post request

Tags: javascript, post, get, axios

In vanilla JS, I'm making a `get` request to a server to retrieve a list of items (a list of messages in a conversation) after the initial page load.  When a reply is sent (a `post` request), I want to append that new message to the list of existing messages without refreshing the whole page (think React).

This is for when the page initially loads:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  axios.get(get_url).then((res) => {
      // Get conversation
  })
})
```

Then, a reply is sent:

```
const sendReply = () => {
  const reply = document.getElementById('replyMessage').value
  axios.post(post_url, {
    // data
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    if (res.status === 201) {
      window.location.reload(true)
    }
  })
}
```

As you can see, I'm refreshing the entire page, which doesn't feel ideal.  There should be a better way to append the new message to the existing conversation.  **Can it be done with vanilla JS?**

**Update**

In case anyone is curious how I solved this, here's what I did:

```
const sendReply = () => {
  const replyText = document.getElementById('replyMessage').value // Get the text of the reply
  axios.post('/messages/api/reply', {
    memberFirstName: Cookies.get('first_name'),
    memberId: Cookies.get('id'),
    conversationId: conversationId,
    reply: replyText
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    if (res.status === 201) {
      const reply = res.data.reply
      messagesArray.push(reply)

      const replyRow = (copy) => {
        return `
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="messageList">
            <div class="well">
              <div align="left">
                <div style="float: left">${copy.from}: <b>${copy.message}</b></div>
                <div style="float: right">Unread</div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        `
      }

      if (messagesArray.length === 2) { // If this is the first reply done without refreshing the page, run this block
        const copy = messagesArray[1]
        replySection = replyRow(copy)
      } else if (messagesArray.length > 2) { // If the user decides to send more than one reply without refreshing the page, run this block
        const copy = messagesArray[messagesArray.length - 1]
        replySection += replyRow(copy)
      }
      document.getElementById('replyId').innerHTML = replySection
      document.getElementById('replyMessage').value = ' '
    } else {
      window.alert("Error")
    }
  })
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const url = window.location.pathname.split('/')
  if (url[1] === 'conversation' && url[2] === conversationId) {
    axios.get(`/conversation/api/${conversationId}`).then((res) => {
      messagesArray.push(res.data.messages)

      let messageList = `<center>`;
      messagesArray[0].map((message) => {
        messageList += `
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="messageList">
            <div class="well">
              <div align="left">`

          message.unread ? (
            messageList += `
              <div style="float: left">${message.from}: <b>${message.message}</b></div>
              <div style="float: right">Unread</div>
              <div style="clear: both"></div>
            `
            ) : (
            messageList += `
              <div style="float: left">${message.from}: ${message.message}</div>
              <div style="float: right">Read</div>
              <div style="clear: both"></div>
            `
            )
          messageList += `</div></div></div>`;
      })

      const reply = `
        <div id="contactForm">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <center>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="replyMessage" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>
              <br />
              <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendReply()">Send</button>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;

      messageList += `<div id="replyId"></div>`; // The reply goes here
      messageList += `</center>`;

      htmlOutput += messageList + reply
      document.getElementById('my-app').innerHTML = htmlOutput;
    })
  } else if (url[1] === 'users' && url[3] === 'about') {

  }
})
```

Comment: Update: I figured it out.  I simply placed a blank `div` tag with an `id` at the bottom of the html code, and then targeted that `id` in the reply's promise with `document.getElementById('replyId').innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do just that using Vanilla JS. You can achieve this in many ways, but this is what I recommend.

1. Create a simple getConversation function responsible only to make a post call and populate the HTML template or list (UL)
2. Now since you want to populate the messages on page load, call the function on page ready like :

   ```
   window.addEventListener('load', () => {
       //your new function 
       getConversationAndPopulateList();
   });
   ```
3. As you already have a sendReply function which makes a post call to send a message, just modify it to register a callback after the reply has been sent successfully.

   ```
   const sendReply(cb) => {
      const replyTxt  = ...
      axios.post(post_url, { ... })
         .then(function(res) {
                if (res.status === 201) {cb();}
          });
   }
   ```
4. Now all you gotta do is when you make a call to sendReply function which is triggered by a user action just call the getConverstion function in the callback or maybe return a promise if that suits you.

   ```
    sendReply(()=>{getConversationAndPopulateList();});
    // and now after evry sent message your conversations will repopulate
   ```

Or better yet you can make the senReply function more singly responsible by adding to arguments and calling it like.

```
sendReply(replyText,()=>{getConversationAndPopulateList();});
```

Comment: My thoughts were also along this line.  Thanks for the detailed reply!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store your messages into an array, and when you're in the `then`, you simply `push` the result in your new array ?

I think this can do the job, if it doesn't refresh the section, you can still use [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) at your selector which will add the content at the end of the section